# Axios post request keeps hanging up

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, async-await, axios

I am making a post request with axios in React.js with the async/await syntax. The request is simply to insert a new user into a table in the mysql database. The request is going through and the data is being inserted, however, my POST request is stuck in pending.

Here is the frontend code in react:

```
export const register = (first_name, last_name, email, password) => async (
  dispatch
) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_REGISTER_REQUEST,
    });

    const user = {
      first_name,
      last_name,
      email,
      password,
    };

    const { data } = await axios.post("api/users/insertdata", user);

    dispatch({
      type: USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });

    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });

    localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(data));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_REGISTER_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

Here is the backend code with node.js and express:

```
  router.post("/insertdata", (req, res) => {
  const { first_name, last_name, email, password } = req.body.first_name;

  let sql = `INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, password) VALUES (?,?,?,?);`;

  connection.query(
    sql,
    [first_name, last_name, email, password],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.status(201);
        console.log("insert complete");
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Hi Keegan, in the code you posted, where is the PUT implementation? I can only see the POST implementation, which according your comment is working perfectly.

Comment: Hello Firmino, since the goal of this function is only to create a new user and not update part of an existing, I am using a POST request.

Comment: I also forgot to mention if I remove the async/await syntax and use .then and .catch, it works perfectly.

Comment: is there error with `export const register = async (first_name, last_name, email, password) = (dispatch) => {}`??? @KeeganAdams

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being a simple oversight on my part. In the backend, i was not returning any data after making the post request to mysql. Please see the if/else statement below.

```
  router.post("/insertdata", (req, res) => {
  const { first_name, last_name, email, password } = req.body.first_name;

  let sql = `INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, password) VALUES (?,?,?,?);`;

  connection.query(
    sql,
    [first_name, last_name, email, password],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.send(req.body);
        res.status(201);
        console.log("insert complete");
      }
    }
  );
});
```